# How to combine images using MagickWand C API?

Tags: c, imagemagick, magickwand

I have a two images And I want to combine them together, similar command for this is `convert one.png two.png +clone -combine displaceMask.png`.
Below is my C Code. I'm not getting the perfect result using C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "MagickWand/MagickWand.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  MagickWand *wand1, *wand2, *wand3;

  wand1 = NewMagickWand();
  wand2 = NewMagickWand();
  wand3 = NewMagickWand();

  MagickReadImage(wand1, "one.png");
  MagickReadImage(wand2, "two.png");

  // convert one.png two.png +clone -combine displaceMask.png
  wand3 = CloneMagickWand(wand2);
  MagickAddImage(wand1, wand2);
  MagickAddImage(wand1, wand3);
  MagickCombineImages(wand1,RGBColorspace);
  MagickWriteImage(wand1,"merge.png");

  if(wand1)wand1 = DestroyMagickWand(wand1);
  if(wand2)wand2 = DestroyMagickWand(wand2);
  if(wand3)wand3 = DestroyMagickWand(wand3);
  MagickWandTerminus();

  return 0;
}
```

These are the images.

one.png

[image]
two.png

[image]
finalResultUsingCMd.png

[image]

merge.png (This image I'm getting using C code. But I want a above image.)
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to included the expected result or describe how the actual result you have shown is not what you require.

Comment: finalResultUsingCMd.png image is the final result I want. Using command I get the image not using C program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer

In addition to capturing combine results, you'll need to reset the wand iterator before applying the `MagickCombineImages`. This is because each time you invoke `MagickAddImage` the internal linked list is pointing to the newly added node. *(Hope I explained that clearly.)*

Quoting some documents...

> After using any images added to the wand using MagickAddImage() or MagickReadImage() will be prepended before any image in the wand.
>
> Also the current image has been set to the first image (if any) in the Magick Wand. Using MagickNextImage() will then set teh current image to the second image in the list (if present).
>
> This operation is similar to MagickResetIterator() but differs in how MagickAddImage(), MagickReadImage(), and MagickNextImage() behaves afterward.

So your example code should look like ...

```c
#include "MagickWand/MagickWand.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  MagickWand
      *wand1,
      *wand2,
      *wand3,
      *result;

  wand1 = NewMagickWand();
  wand2 = NewMagickWand();

  MagickReadImage(wand1, "one.png");
  MagickReadImage(wand2, "two.png");

  // convert one.png two.png +clone -combine displaceMask.png
  wand3 = CloneMagickWand(wand2);
  MagickAddImage(wand1, wand2);
  MagickAddImage(wand1, wand3);
  MagickSetFirstIterator(wand1);
  result = MagickCombineImages(wand1, MagickGetImageColorspace(wand1));
  MagickWriteImage(result,"merge.png");

  wand1 = DestroyMagickWand(wand1);
  wand2 = DestroyMagickWand(wand2);
  wand3 = DestroyMagickWand(wand3);
  result = DestroyMagickWand(result);
  MagickWandTerminus();

  return 0;
}
```

[image: copy of merge.png]

### Original Answer

The `MagickCombineImages` method should return a pointer `MagickWand *` containing the result of the combine action. <s>The behavior of this method has changed between version of IM 6 & IM 7, so it's more than possible that a bug exists, or implementation has adjusted.</s> I'm not around IM 7 to verify at the moment, but here's a work around.

```c
// convert one.png two.png +clone -combine displaceMask.png
wand3 = CloneMagickWand(wand2);
MagickCompositeImage(wand1, wand2, CopyGreenCompositeOp, MagickTrue, 0, 0);
MagickCompositeImage(wand1, wand3, CopyBlueCompositeOp,  MagickTrue, 0, 0);
MagickWriteImage(wand1, "merge.png");
```

[image: merge.png]

Comment: Hello @emcconville, both solution works perfectly. I understood the first approach. Could you explain a bit about second approach? And which one you recommend?

Comment: The composite solution replaces dst color channel by copying src data. This works as expected because your example images are already grayscale images. The combine method would be preferred as it will actually calculate / resolve gray values & apply to all channels w/ respecting color traits

Comment: one quick question. Why SetImageGravity is not working with crop? To make it work, I passed the X and Y coordinates in crop function.

Comment: Remember your writing an application in a high level language. You are responsible for handling the math, and don't assume that all behavioral short-cuts from the CLI application apply. I would recommend reading the source code to see how Cristy design the architecture.